# reg: Manage Dashboards link in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

In Sonar version 3.4.1 a Manage Dashboards link is used for creating global and project dashboards from an admin ID. As a part of the security config setup, we can create new users. Manage dashboard link, however, is visible for new users we've just created.

So, I request your advice on is there are any options to hide the link from anyone except for the admin.

Answer (score 0):

The "Manage dashboard" link that you see must remain always available: it allows a user to create a dashboard that willbe available only for him.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, Thanks for your immediate reply. I changed the Sonar dashboard profile to Sonar way with Findbugs. Earlier I made the settings like users/developers can able to create only Project dashboards. Not sure, because of some test checks, now I can see the users also can able to create global dashboards instead of project dashboards. Please advise how to revert back for the creation of project dashboards from the users end..Thanks once again